# Can't connect to DB while installing Drupal 8

Tags: 8, database, installation

Can't connect to DB while installing Drupal 8. DB is located on localhost acording to direct admin but i can get to DB only when using ip address  in advanced options of drupal installation otherwise i get: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. With ip entered it says  following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user on server.......

I have tried different  users and db that i have created on server (granted all permissions). No luck.

I have no problem logging to that DB with that user using phpmyadmin.  What does it seem to be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of localhost, try 127.0.0.1

Comment: Worker.  Thanks.  any ideal why we have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost....  And why it didn't work when i used server ip address?  Just curious.

Comment: localhost is an alias of 127.0.0.1, and sometimes some configurations haven't got that alias registered.

Comment: Usually with php/mysql, localhost connects through a socket file, which is AFAIK faster but it looks like that is misconfigured on your system. 127.0.0.1 uses the network stack and is not affected by that misconfiguration. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html for more information.